# Fetch MySQL records where one condition satisfies NULL and other satisfies NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am firing a query in my database as follows :

```
SELECT id, firmName, website FROM master_table WHERE 
 (firmName IS NULL OR firmName = '') 
  AND 
 (website IS NOT NULL OR website != '' );
```

I want all the records where firm name should be empty and the corresponding website should not be empty

But it still results in records where I might encounter a **NULL** or **EMPTY** website.

Can someone please tell me how to do it properly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT id, firmName, website 
FROM master_table 
WHERE (firmName IS NULL OR firmName = '') 
  AND (website IS NOT NULL AND website != '' )
                            ^---- and not or
```

Comment: Thank You ! Yes it solved the case. Please wait for 10 mins till I am eligible to accept the answer